# Can Gauntlets of Energy Transformation affect a Duskblade's channeled spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Could a Duskblade use Gauntlets of Energy Transformation (*Magic Item Compendium*, p. 102) to alter a channeled shocking grasp spell to another form of energy?

Their description states that the gauntlets

> allow you to change the type of energy produced by any weapon you hold.

Once you have channeled shocking grasp could you use a swift action to transform the damage with the gauntlets to another type of energy damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specific to your question:

No, the gauntlets wouldn't do that. The energy of [Shocking Grasp](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shockingGrasp.htm) is coming from the spell itself. Therefore, only a metamagic feat, or metamagic-like effect, could change the type of energy from Shocking Grasp; such as Energy Admixture (Complete Arcane).

The type of energy of the weapon that the gauntlets would change, would be from, for example, [Flaming Burst](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#flamingBurst) to [Icy Burst](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#icyBurst). That type of energy does come from the weapon, and not a spell.

If you are attacking while channeling a spell, you could still use the gauntlets to change the energy of the weapon if it is enchanted as such - but would not have an effect on the spell the weapon is channeling. So the gauntlets would have a benefit, especially if you are attacking something that is prone to a specific energy type.

Answer (score 4):

I would say no.

In your scenario, the weapon isn't *producing* energy, the wielder is.
The weapon is just conducting that energy to the target.